# Unable to read folder files correctly using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

I am trying to implement simple features DNN using tensorflow. I need to iterate through every folder in the directory and the code will read every csv files contain in a particular folder. I have got multiple folders in A_Device_Motion directory with name as 'dws_1', 'dws_2', 'jog_9' etc. Each folder contains data of 24 subjects activity in csv files. I am trying to iterate throught the folder data and giving Activity variable a specific name with each iteration. But the problem i am facing is that my code is not able to read the folder name completely and giving me a keyError. And my folder strcuture looks like this [image: Here]
Here is my Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\TechProBox\Desktop\python.py", line 21, in <module>
df['Activity'] = Activety_Types[j[49:52]]
KeyError: 'ws_'
```

My Python Code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sklearn
from glob import glob
import os
import itertools
import tensorflow as tf
print(os.listdir("C:/Users/TechProBox/Desktop/A_DeviceMotion_data"))
Activety_Types = {'dws':1,'jog':2,'sit':3,'std':4,'ups':5,'wlk':6}        
listDict = list(Activety_Types.keys())
Folders = glob('C:/Users/TechProBox/Desktop/A_DeviceMotion_data/*_*')
Folders = [s for s in Folders if "csv" not in s]
Df_all_list = []
Exp = 0
Segment_Size = 400
for j  in Folders:
  Csv = glob(j + '/*' )
  for i in Csv:
    df = pd.read_csv(i)
    df['Activity'] = Activety_Types[j[49:52]]
    df['Sub_Num'] = i[len(j)+5:-4]
    df['Exp_num'] = 1
    ExpNum = np.zeros((df.shape[0])) 
    for i in range(0,df.shape[0]-Segment_Size,Segment_Size):
        ExpNum[range(i,i+Segment_Size)] = i/Segment_Size +Exp*100 
    df['Exp_num'] = ExpNum
    Df_all_list.append(df)
    Exp += 1        

Df_all = pd.concat(Df_all_list,axis=0)  
Df_all.head()
plt.plot([1,2,3])
for i in range(6):
D = Df_all[Df_all['Activity']==i+1]
plt.subplot(3,2,i+1)
plt.plot(D['userAcceleration.z'][:200])
plt.title(listDict[i])
plt.ylim([-1, 1])

plt.tight_layout()
```

I did not pasted the whole code here but i think this code is enough for understanding. I am facing error on this line `df['Activity'] = Activety_Types[j[49:52]]`
PS: Code is not mine i took it from kaggle.

Comment: First, doublecheck your indentation in your post, something seems off. Second, it's looking for a key, `ws_` that isn't in your dictionary. I would add to your loop a `print(j[49:52]) and make sure you're getting what you think you are

Comment: @G.Anderson you are right when i added `print(j[49:52])` in my code it just showed me this output here  `ws_` this should not be since i want it to read 'dws_1' and so on. How can i fix this?

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like the data you're reading isn't the same as what the kaggle code used, so you're going to have to figure out what the data _actually_ contains, and update your `Activety_Types` dictionary accordingly. (While you're doing that, check the [PEP-8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) for variable names, all should be "lowercase, with words separated by underscores" for best practice)

Comment: @G.Anderson the code is completely same as the code in kaggle kernel. Just the difference of directory path is in the code. Since i have downloaded the data in my machine and gave the path of my directory. I tried using `print (j[48:60])` now it showed me `dws_1` but did not move forward and read other names.

Comment: @G.Anderson as for the variables name i just removed the variables named the folders dws1, dws2, dws3 so it did not show me any error on that but unfortunately in this way it did not read any folder and just moved on. I checked by printing so i showed me nothing.

Comment: Obviously there is some difference between the data as you have it and the data is the kaggle competitor had it. Unfortunately, you're going to have to look into the data yourself and see why it doesn't work the same on your machine; `dws_1` is also not a key in the dictionary `Activety_Types`, so it will likely also not work

Comment: @G.Anderson the data that the competitor has used is the same data tha i am using. I tried to change the path a little bit since it was reading my full path. I put the data in current working directory and directly gave the path. it did read the directory containing folders but did not read the data inside those folders of csv files so it gave me error `No objects to concatenate`.

Comment: I'm assuming the new error is happening on the line `Df_all = pd.concat(Df_all_list,axis=0)`. If so, it means that your dataframes are not being created, which means that somehow your files aren't structured the way you think. All I can tell you is to add debugging or more `print()` statements to see what you're actually reading, maybe after `for j in Folders:` you add `print("Folder {}\n".format(j))` and after `for i in Csv:` you put `print("File {}\n".format(i))`

Comment: @G.Anderson I was able to solve the problem. The correct code is now provided as the answer. Thanks for your help dude :)

Comment: I'm glad you were able to solve the problem, happy to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently i was giving wrong names of the folders that needed to be added and there were some other minor mistakes in the code too. I had to give exact names of each and every folder to run the program and it worked here is the correct code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sklearn
from glob import glob
import os
import itertools
import tensorflow as tf
print(os.listdir("A_DeviceMotion_data"))
Activety_Types = {'dws_1':1,'jog_9':2,'sit_5':3,'std_6':4,'ups_3':5,'wlk_7':6, 'dws_2':7, 'dws_11':8, 'jog_16':9, 'sit_13':10, 'std_14':11, 'ups_4':12, 'ups_12':13,'wlk_8':14,'wlk_15':15}        
listDict = list(Activety_Types.keys())
Folders = glob('C:/Users/TechProBox/Desktop/A_DeviceMotion_data/*_*')
Folders = [s for s in Folders if "csv" not in s]
Df_all_list = []
Exp = 0
Segment_Size = 400
for j  in Folders:
    print("Folder {}\n".format(j))
    Csv = glob(j + '/*' )
    for i in Csv:
        print (i)
        print (j)
        print("HERE")
        df = pd.read_csv(i)
        print(Activety_Types[j[48:56]])
        df['Activity'] = Activety_Types[j[48:56]]
        print("HERE1")

        df['Sub_Num'] = i[len(j)+5:-4]
        df['Exp_num'] = 1
        ExpNum = np.zeros((df.shape[0])) 
        for i in range(0,df.shape[0]-Segment_Size,Segment_Size):
            ExpNum[range(i,i+Segment_Size)] = i/Segment_Size +Exp*100 
        df['Exp_num'] = ExpNum
        Df_all_list.append(df)
        Exp += 1        

Df_all = pd.concat(Df_all_list,axis=0)  
Df_all.head()
plt.plot([1,2,3])
for i in range(6):
    D = Df_all[Df_all['Activity']==i+1]
    plt.subplot(3,2,i+1)
    plt.plot(D['userAcceleration.z'][:200])
    plt.title(listDict[i])
    plt.ylim([-1, 1])
plt.tight_layout()

df_sum = Df_all.groupby('Exp_num', axis=0).mean().reset_index()
df_sum.columns = df_sum.columns.str.replace('.','_sum_')

df_sum_SS = np.power(Df_all.astype(float),2).groupby('Exp_num', axis=0).median().reset_index() 
df_sum_SS.columns = df_sum_SS.columns.str.replace('.','_sumSS_')

df_max = Df_all.groupby('Exp_num', axis=0).max().reset_index()
df_max.columns = df_max.columns.str.replace('.','_max_')

df_min = Df_all.groupby('Exp_num', axis=0).min().reset_index()
df_min.columns = df_min.columns.str.replace('.','_min_')

df_skew = Df_all.groupby('Exp_num', axis=0).skew().reset_index()
df_skew.columns = df_skew.columns.str.replace('.','_skew_')

df_std = Df_all.groupby('Exp_num', axis=0).std().reset_index()
df_std.columns = df_std.columns.str.replace('.','_std_')

Df_Features = pd.concat([ df_max , df_sum[df_sum.columns[2:-2]], 
                         df_min[df_min.columns[2:-2]], df_sum_SS[df_sum_SS.columns[2:-2]], 
                         df_std[df_std.columns[2:-2]], df_skew[df_skew.columns[2:-2]]], axis=1)

Df_Features_1 = Df_Features.drop(['Exp_num','Unnamed: 0','Activity','Sub_Num'],axis=1)
Labels = Df_Features['Activity']

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(Df_Features_1, Labels, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

X_shape = Df_Features_1.shape[1]
Cluss_Num = len(Activety_Types)
X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=[None,X_shape])
y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape = [None,Cluss_Num])
Hold_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)


def Init_Wightes(shape1):
    W = tf.truncated_normal(shape1,stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(W)

def Init_bias(shape1):
    b =  tf.constant(0.1,shape=shape1)
    return tf.Variable(b)

def FC_layer(input1,shape1):

    W = Init_Wightes(shape1)
    B = Init_bias([shape1[1]])
    Wx = tf.matmul(input1,W)
    Wx_b = tf.add(Wx,B)
    return tf.nn.relu(Wx_b)


H1_size = 54
H2_size = 24

H1 = FC_layer(X, [X_shape,H1_size])
H1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(H1,keep_prob=Hold_prob)
y_pred = FC_layer(H1_drop,[H1_size,len(Activety_Types)])

Err = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=y,logits=y_pred))
Optimaizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
Train = Optimaizer.minimize(Err)
Init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

BatchSize = 64
label_binarizer = sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()
label_binarizer.fit(range(Cluss_Num))


X_train_Np = np.array(X_train,dtype=np.float32)
Y_train_Np = np.array(y_train,dtype=np.float32)
X_test_Np = np.array(X_test,dtype=np.float32)
Y_test_Np = np.array(y_test,dtype=np.float32)
Y_test_OH  = label_binarizer.transform(Y_test_Np)
Y_test_OH = np.array(Y_test_OH,dtype=np.float32)
Batches = np.array(range(0,X_train_Np.shape[0]-BatchSize,BatchSize))
accuracy = 10
misclass = 1
steps = 5000

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(Init)
    for i in range(steps): 
        BastchNum = np.mod(i,len(Batches)-1)
        batch_x = X_train_Np[Batches[BastchNum] : Batches[BastchNum+1] ,:]
        batch_y = Y_train_Np[Batches[BastchNum] : Batches[BastchNum+1] ]
        batch_y_OH  = label_binarizer.transform(batch_y)
        batch_y_OH = np.array(batch_y_OH,dtype=np.float32)
        sess.run(Train,feed_dict={X:batch_x,y:batch_y_OH,Hold_prob:0.5}) 
        if i%100 == 0:   
            print('Currently on step {}'.format(i))
            print('Accuracy is:')
            # Test the Train Model
            matches = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_pred,1),tf.argmax(y,1))
            acc = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(matches,tf.float32))
            print(sess.run(acc,feed_dict={X:X_test_Np,y:Y_test_OH,Hold_prob:1.0}))
            print('\n')
            Conf = tf.confusion_matrix(tf.arg_max(y_pred,1),tf.arg_max(y,1))
            C1 = sess.run(Conf,feed_dict={X:X_test_Np,y:Y_test_OH,Hold_prob:1.0})
def plot_confusion_matrix(cm,
    target_names,
    title='Confusion matrix',
    cmap=None,
    normalize=True):
    accuracy = np.trace(cm) / float(np.sum(cm))
    misclass = 1 - accuracy
    if cmap is None:
        cmap = plt.get_cmap('Blues')
        plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
        plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
        plt.title(title)
        plt.colorbar()
        if target_names is not None:
            tick_marks = np.arange(len(target_names))
            plt.xticks(tick_marks, target_names, rotation=45)
            plt.yticks(tick_marks, target_names)
        if normalize:
            cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
        thresh = cm.max() / 1.5 if normalize else cm.max() / 2
        for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):
            if normalize:
                plt.text(j, i, "{:0.4f}".format(cm[i, j]),
                    horizontalalignment="center",
                    color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")
            else:
                plt.text(j, i, "{:,}".format(cm[i, j]),
                    horizontalalignment="center",
                    color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.ylabel('True label')
plt.xlabel('Predicted label\naccuracy={:0.4f}; misclass={:0.4f}'.format(accuracy, misclass))
plt.show()
Conf = tf.confusion_matrix(tf.arg_max(y_pred,1),tf.arg_max(y,1))
plot_confusion_matrix(C1,target_names=[*Activety_Types])
```